# Where was this train photograph taken?

Tags: trains, identify-this

Where was this train photograph taken? I found it as a header on [langsamreisen.de](http://www.langsamreisen.de/schienenreisen/europa_asien/), but that page does not specify where it is. The filename contains the phrase `tren-del-sur`, but I don't think it's at the 6.4 km [Tren del Sur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tren_del_Sur) described on Wikipedia.

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that it should be the train you mentioned. "Tren del Sur" sounds a bit generic and the photo's name does not make a reference to wikipedia.

Comment: I do *not* think it is the train I mentioned, that's why I wrote *I don't think...* Incidentally, the locomotive does look like a [Plymouth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mercedita_Train_2.JPG) but those are far from unique either.

Comment: From the colour of the last carriage one can see that it is Peru. How precisely do you want it?

Comment: If it is indeed Peru that already pins it down very significantly! I don't know really how precise I want it, but the more precise the nicer.

Comment: Somewhere along the network of RailPeru? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PeruRail This used to be called "Ferrocarril del Sur", which would explain the "tren del sur" tag in the picture's name ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming it's recent, it's almost certainly between Cusco and Puno.

Source? Well, it's circumstantial, but bear with me.

- I've been there, and the scenery immediately made me think of my bus journey between the two cities.
- the second carriage (blue and yellow) is the colours of the PeruRail trains.
- at present, the only routes on PeruRail are [Cusco to Peru](http://www.perurail.com/routes_and_maps.php?des=2) or [Cusco to Aguas Calientes/Machu Picchu](http://www.perurail.com/routes_and_maps.php?des=1).  The second journey is mostly though river valleys, and looks decidedly different.

As it's open plains, I'd also plot it as between Puno and La Raya, if I had to guess, as the scenery changes in the second half. But I can't guarantee it.

However, there USED to be a train down to Arequipa as well, now I believe running only on demand for large groups.  So if it's a stock photo, it might have come from that journey as some of the landscape would be similar.  But it's a lot less likely.